# Why MoveWindow Function disable border resizing when used in a loop?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

When I use `MoveWindow` function just one time then it works fine. e.g

```
MoveWindow(handles[tempIndex + 1], x, 0, cx, cy, true);
```

But when i put it in a loop to move many windows it move all windows side by side but after that border re sizing(using mouse) is disabled. When i hover mouse on the border of a window then re size icon appears when i hold down left mouse button and try to move the border then it does not move and seems the border is fixed and not resizable. Here is my code

```
 private void resizeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
EnumWindows(new EnumWindowsProc(EnumTheWindows), IntPtr.Zero);
int width = 1366 / size;
int x = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
      MoveWindow(handles[i], x, 0, width, 775, true);
      UpdateWindow(handles[i]);
      x = x + width + 1;
      }
}
    protected static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
            {

        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        RECT rct = new RECT();
        placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(placement);
        int size1 = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
        GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, ref placement);
        if (size1++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
        {
            if (!IsIconic(hWnd))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size1);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size1);
                if (sb.ToString() != "DataCardMonitor" && sb.ToString() != "Program Manager")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
                    handles[tempHandle] = hWnd;
                    GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rct);
                    rect[tempHandle] = rct;
                    tempHandle++;
                    size++;
                }

            }


        }
        return true;
    }
```

Why it is happening? is there any work around for that?

Comment: Whose windows are these?

Comment: FYI, I don't think that UpdateWindow is necessary. If the last parameter of MoveWindow is true then a paint message is sent to the window after it is repositioned. UpdateWindow sends the same event message. You are requesting the window to repaint twice.

Comment: Repositioning many windows is what [DeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632681.aspx) was invented for.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan these windows does not belong to my program. These are just windows being shown on desktop.I am just positioning them on desktop.